# How should I design my model architecture?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I have a dataset consisting of N presence points of a crop in a certain region. And I have 19 bioclimatic variables (temperature, precipitation, etc) which I extracted from .tif files. I have an input of size (N,32,32,19) where N is no of sample points and 32X32 is an image patch containing that point as a center to leverage CNN abilities to learn local context and 19 bioclimatic variables for every pixel.

I'm confused with the CNN architecture.

Comment: Do you want to predict the 19 bioclimatic variables? Or what are you predicting? Also, what confuses you about the CNN architecture?